# Usage of the EXISTS function?

Tags: mdx

What is a use case of the exists function?

It seems that that is the default behavior of a query (if I'm not mistaken) to automatically do an `exists` and not return any results if they aren't there:

```
EXISTS([Team].[Name].[Name].[Green Bay Packers], [Team].[Name].[Name].members),

-- vs 
[Team].[Name].[Name].[Green Bay Packers]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the MDX Exists function is to get the set of tuples of the first set specified that exist with one or more tuples of the second set specified. we use exists in some setuations like we want to get all the cities of a specific region.

```
 EXISTS([City].[City], [region].[region].[Region].&[1])
```

Wich makes it a verry usefull  function.